# dart pub fail behind a proxy - is there a way to install the packages manually?

Tags: dart, dart-pub

There is a known issue with using Pub dart in a corporate network using a proxy (on windows machine at least). You cannot even run the samples as they make use of pub to get the packages. 
if you run the samples first from a network without a proxy, it works perfectly fine (the packages have been installed) when you run them from behind the proxy.

My question is: **how can I install the packages manually?**

I can of course get them from git for example, but what do I have to do afterward to "install them" I am confused with what goes in the Dart install directory, the user directory and the symlinks that seem to be necessary.
May be I missed something but I did not find any good doc about that.

thanks,

f.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24021315

Answer (score 5):

You can download package files manually, copy them to `packages` folder and then symlink to it from other places which use them (on Windows Vista and later, you can use `mklink` command). You can also just copy them everywhere, instead of symlinking, but that complicates maintenance.

Simpler solution, if you have access to full installation from the machine without proxy, is to copy packages folder from there.

Even simpler, I sometimes keep test projects in my dropbox folder, so i just update when I am on my home computer, and it works fine on my office machine behind the proxy.

That being said, I was able to fix the proxy issue by specifying following system environment variables (address/port combination below is made up, use the correct one for your setup):

```
HTTP_PROXY:  192.168.123.123:1234  
HTTPS_PROXY: 192.168.123.123:1234
```

in addition, to enable DartEditor to check for editor updates, add following to your DartEditor.ini file:

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=192.168.123.123
-Dhttp.proxyPort=1234
```

If your proxy uses authentication, than check also following settings (mine doesn't so I can't tell):

```
-Dhttp.proxyUser=XXX
-Dhttp.proxyPassword=XXX
```

Comment: thanks for the tips, i'll copy manually and install in the packages folder.

about proxy settings :

settings the proxy info in the editor config file works fine. I am able to get the update.

I tried to setup the proxy settings in the system env variable. I tried using name and /or IP address.
here is the error i get (using name or ip give the same error)

--- May 29, 2013 1:01:46 PM Running pub install ... ---
Pub install failed, [255] Resolving dependencies...
Uncaught Error: SocketIOException: Failed host name lookup (OS Error: No such host is known.

, errno = 11001)
...

Comment: dartini parameters do not work for me (win 7, anonymous proxy).
"Pub get" manually acknoledges the proxy setting, butt fails with some weird path issue:
"\\rdev\DFSRoot$\home\moelrue\Application Data\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\browser-0.9.0\lib of Link.create on Windows cannot be converted to start with a drive letter.  Unexpected error., path = ''"

seems one can't use it inside a company ...

Answer (score 2):

Another way to go is using the command line tools for getting the packages:

(On Windows)

1. Proxy Settings

   - In the cmd (not persistent):

     ```
     SET HTTP_PROXY=proxy:port
     SET HTTPS_PROXY=proxy:port
     ```
   - Or as Zdeslav Vojkovic suggested - specify system environment variables (persistent).
2. Go to the sample app folder

   ```
   cd <path-to-dart-installation>\samples\angular_todo\
   ```
3. Run the required pub command:

   ```
   <path-to-dart-installation>\dart-sdk\bin\pub.bat get
   ```

Project is automatically updated in the dart editor.

---

Edit:
Try as well setting the proxy information as system environment variables, but using lower case e.g.

```
http_proxy=proxy:port
https_proxy=proxy:port
```

As far I as know Windows environment variables are not case sensitive. However dart editor seems to make difference.