# Dart Plugin For Eclipse - Using a network Proxy

Tags: eclipse, dart

I'm currently using Eclipse: Kepler and just installed the Dart plug-in via Help->Install New Software.

Download went through without a hitch and I attempted to create my first dummy project to see if it was all working fine similar to how it's displayed in http://blog.dartwatch.com/2013/01/integrating-dart-into-eclipse-and-your.html

However, I'm getting some pub errors where it can not download of the required libraries.  The error in question looks like this

```
Got socket error trying to find package "browser" at https://pub.dartlang.org.

SocketException: Connection failed (OS Error: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
, errno = 10060), address = pub.dartlang.org, port = 443
```

That said, is there an additional configuration/ini file that I need to modify for this to work?  I've checked my system and environment variables - nothing seems out of place.  I can use the build in browser inside of eclipse and download other packages through the Eclipse Marketplace.

Comment: I suppose this applies here too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16808883

Comment: possible duplicate of [dart pub fail behind a proxy - is there a way to install the packages manually?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16808883/dart-pub-fail-behind-a-proxy-is-there-a-way-to-install-the-packages-manually)

Answer (score 1):

[Issue 5454](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=5454) is relating to using pub behind a proxy and marked as "Fixed", but there's still some discussion going on after it was marked as Fixed, so I'm not completely sure what the status is today. There's some discussion of different behaviour from the editor though.