# Error while running angular dart tutorial available on github

Tags: angularjs, dart, angular-dart

I am new to angular-dart. I have no prior knowledge of DART. Working on angular since last 3 months. I have downloaded the code from github. Then i opened the chapter 1 code through File->open in Dart Editor.The file structure of the project is,
Chapter_01 ---> 1) pubspec.yaml
2) Web
2.1)index.html
2.2)main.dart
3) README

in index.html there is reference to

The first and last js files are missing. Where could i get them or how to generate them.
I right clicked on pubspec.yaml and chose the option Pub Get,for that i got the error as

"--- Jan 31, 2014 8:13:33 PM Running pub get ... ---
Pub get failed, [1] Resolving dependencies....Got socket error trying to find package angular at https://pub.dartlang.org.

** Warning: Application may fail to run since packages did not get installed.Try running pub get again. ** "
Also, in the main.dart file i am getting the error for the line "import 'package:angular/angular.dart';"
as "Target of URI does not exist: 'package:angular/angular.dart'"

Also i tried to ping the https://pub.dartlang.org .I got Destination net unreachable.
But the same URL is accessible through my browser.

Kindly help me to resolve the issue.
I am using windows 7.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Mohan Savant

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Yes, i am running the code in corporate network. Does that will be the issue?

Comment: Yes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16808883/dart-pub-fail-behind-a-proxy-is-there-a-way-to-install-the-packages-manually

Comment: Also i am not able to see 'Install' under Tools menu.As it it advised under the 'installing' instructions.

Answer (score 0):

It's absolutely necessary that `pub get` succeeds. It's useless to try something else before that works.

- Sometimes there are temporary problems with pub.dartlang.org. How often have you tried? (never experienced this myself though)
- Another known source of such problems is a proxy.