# Network Connection Proxies in Dart Editor

Tags: dart, dart-editor

Eclipse has a "Network Connections" page in its preferences that allows one to use proxies for network connections, so if I am behind a firewall I can use these connections. I don't see any such option in the Dart Editor. So, while I am at work, I cannot update from the network because of this. I can set the proxy in a browser, but not in Dart Editor. With a direct connection to an ISP, everything is okay, but *not* from an internal network.

Is there some way to fix this issue? If there is another way to allow the Dart Editor to connect to a network proxy I would be pleased.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set environment variables

https://www.dartlang.org/tools/editor/troubleshoot.html#pub-get-firewall

```
http_proxy=http://<yourproxy>.<yourdomain>.com:9090/
https_proxy=https://<yourproxy>.<yourdomain>.com:9090/
no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.0/8
```

If your proxy needs authentication, the setup will look more like the following:

```
http_proxy=http://<username>:<password>@<yourproxy>.<yourdomain>.com:9090/
https_proxy=https://<username>:<password>@<yourproxy>.<yourdomain>.com:9090/
```

**DartEditor is no more**

<strike>To enable Dart Editor to check for updates, add the following to the DartEditor.ini file:</strike>

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=<yourproxy>.<yourdomain>.com
-Dhttp.proxyPort=9090
-Dhttps.proxyHost=<yourproxy>.<yourdomain>.com
-Dhttps.proxyPort=9090
```

If you need a user name and password for authentication, add:

```
-Dhttp.proxyUser=<username>
-Dhttp.proxyPassword=<passwordstring>
-Dhttps.proxyUser=<username>
-Dhttps.proxyPassword=<passwordstring>
```

See also https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/24080

Comment: How do I set the environmental variable. I know how to set a Windows environment variable but if the reference is to that. I tried it but nothing happens.

Comment: It seems I missed your comment. You need to restart the application after you change environment variables to take effect. When you started the application from a command prompt you also need to close and reopen the command prompt.