# Pub dart update from behind proxy

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

Any solution for updating dart from behind a web proxy server? I am behind campus web proxy so it is giving errors in updating.I am using Ubuntu Server 12.04. Any workarounds?

Comment: possible duplicate of [dart pub fail behind a proxy - is there a way to install the packages manually?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16808883/dart-pub-fail-behind-a-proxy-is-there-a-way-to-install-the-packages-manually)

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24021315

Comment: possible duplicate of [Network Connection Preference Page in Dart IDE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24021315/network-connection-preference-page-in-dart-ide)